# How does Ionic decide which Android emulator to launch?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am following this for Android platform: http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ (cmd> ionic emulate android) . It builds ok, and I know the apk works on a phone, but I want to figure out how does it decided which Android Virtual Device to launch. At the moment, it start up a v2.2 emulator by default and then complains it's too old while trying to install the apk. I want to use v4.1 or higher (I have the relevant SDKs installed through previous native Android development using Eclipse.)

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, just specify the emulator target.

e.g. `ionic emulate android --target="Nexus_6P_API_25"`

Check the AVD manager for a list of available and installed virtual devices.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of found an answer myself. Instead of using Google Android emulator, one can use
[Genymotion](http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionic-cli-faq/#android-sdk). And use can set the device screen size and Android version.